# django test override_settings at class-level overwrites settings before they can be initialized

Tags: python, django, django-testing, pytest-django

Unsure if I've stumbled on a bug. I am using `@override_settings` in my tests and observe a different behavior annotating this on my test classes vs test methods. Specifically if I put the annotation on the class, the first time I run through the `django.conf.LazySettings.__getattr__()`, `self._wrapped` already returns my initialized override, and therefore the `self._setup()` is never called and the rest of my settings are not loaded.

e.g.:

```
@override_settings(FOO="mock_val") #prevents regular settings
class FooTests(TestCase):

    @override_settings(FOO="mock_val") #allows regular settings
    test_foo(self):
```

LazySettings source: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py)

Comment: I’m wondering if add the decorator on the setUp class will get the result you want

Comment: yes, decorator on setup works as well! So I guess is putting the annotation on the class itself not recommended/supported?

Comment: Read the warning and the notes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.modify_settings